# PHP: create an array of functions with a for loop

Tags: php

I have some code that needs a list of functions.
I want to create automatically part of this list.
Scope rules in PHP prevent my following approach to the problem from working:

```php
$list=[];
$i=0;
for(;$i<10; $i++) {
  $list []= function() { 
    // code that --depends-- on $i, like:
    return $i;
  };
}

// example of use of the 7th function in the list:
echo $list[6]();
```

Outputs (on my test machine I have PHP 8.1.2)

```
Warning: Undefined variable $i in [...]/test.php on line [...]
```

Because when the 7th anonymous function in $list is called by the last line, its body refers to $i, which is local to the function body and does **not** refer to the loop variable $i. If $i were declared global it would not issue a warning but would not do what I want either.

Notes:

- In some posts here, OO programming is mentioned. But I do not know enough about OO programming and PHP to see how.
- `create_function` is no more available in PHP 8
- I know there are simpler code for outputting 6, like `echo 6;` thanks.

Comment: If is a simple execution, try with https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Comment: Thanks. From your link it appears the arrow seems to implicitly use the "use" keyword proposed in Daniel Cheung's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
<?php
$list=[];

for($i=0;$i<10; $i++) {
  $list []= function() use ($i) { // <--
    return $i;
  };
}

echo $list[6]();
```

You are missing the capture phrase in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

Comment: Thanks!! This is so simple, I'm glad this keyword exists.